# MYSQL-I want to add a column named "total_marks" in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

MYSQL-I want to add a column named "total_marks" in **mysql database** whose values automatically gets inserted by inserting marks of other columns in same row, so other columns are marks of five subjects and i don't want to add all manually and then insert  into total_marks  ,it should be functionally dependent on other five columns, so how to do it?? lets say table name is marks and five of six columns are  ***english,hindi ,maths,science,social and sixth column is "total_marks"***.should i have to do it manually ??

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Create table

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
name varchar(25),
english int(11),
hindi int(11),
maths int(11),
science int(11),
social int(11),
total_marks int(11)
);
```

### Step 2: Create Trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_mark_insert;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_mark_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.total_marks = NEW.english + NEW.hindi + NEW.maths + NEW.science + NEW.social;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### Step 3:

```
    INSERT INTO student  INSERT INTO student (name,english,hindi,maths,science,social)
VALUES('Karthi',70,80,60,35,50);
```

- INSERT english,hindi ,maths,science and social  marks.
- Above trigger will do the total_marks.

### Check the table

```
SELECT * FROM student;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Sir!